# Converting nested xml to nested html recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I want to convert nested xml to nested ul li structure. I have written all the code but there is a error in it. I have spent whole day but can't getting it to work. The error can be very simple. Can anyone please look into that and reply to me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var str = ""; var temp = "";
        function makeTree() {
            treeUL = createNestedTree($('root'));
            $("#tree").append(treeUL);
        }

        function createNestedTree(obj) {
            if($(obj).children().size() != 0) {
                str = str + "<li>" + $(obj).attr("name") + "</li><ul>";
                $(obj).children("item").each(function() {
                    returnValue = createNestedTree($(this));
                    str = str + returnValue;
                });

                return str + "</ul>";
            }
            else {
                temp = "<li>" + $(obj).attr("name") + "</li><ul></ul>";
                return temp;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- xml structure start -->
    <root>
        <item name="a">
            <item name="d">
                <item name="d"></item>
                <item name="e"></item>     
                <item name="f"></item>
            </item>
            <item name="g"></item>
            <item name="h"></item>
        </item>
        <item name="b"></item>
        <item name="c"></item>
    </root>
    <!-- xml structure end -->

    <a href="javascript:makeTree()">Make Tree</a>
    <div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/b2eMe/28/)

I have created xml inside html because I do not know how to refer external xml into fiddle. But it behaves exactly like xml when passed to the function so no issues about that.

Comment: One small error is that you're wrapping a jquery object within another jquery object needlessly. Here are my suggested changes: http://jsfiddle.net/b2eMe/31/. Basically, either pass `'root'` to `createNestedTree` or use `obj` directly within the function. In my link, I changed it to `$obj` to indicate it's a jquery object, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: Also, can you please post a sample of your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var makeTree = function makeTree(nodes) {
  var $result = $('<ul>');

  $.each(nodes, function (_, node) {
    var
      $li = $('<li>').text(node.getAttribute('name')).appendTo($result),
      $children = $(node).children('item');

    if ($children.length > 0) {
      makeTree($children).appendTo($li);
    }
  });

  return $result;
};

makeTree($('root').children('item')).appendTo('#tree');
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8zeep/2/

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following fiddle which solves your problem - http://jsfiddle.net/b2eMe/36/

**CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var str = ""; var temp = "";
        function makeTree() {
            createNestedTree($('root'));
            $("#tree").append(str);
        }

        function createNestedTree(obj) {
            str += '<ul>'; 
            var children = obj.children();        
            if(children.size() != 0) {
                $.each(children, function (index, value) {
                    var $value = $(value);
                    str += '<li>' + $value.attr('name');
                    createNestedTree($value);
                    str += '</li>';
                })
            }
            str += '</ul>';     
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- xml structure start -->
    <root>
        <item name="a">
            <item name="d">
                <item name="d"></item>
                <item name="e"></item>     
                <item name="f"></item>
            </item>
            <item name="g"></item>
            <item name="h"></item>
        </item>
        <item name="b"></item>
        <item name="c"></item>
    </root>
    <!-- xml structure end -->

    <a href="javascript:makeTree()">Make Tree</a>
    <div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: +1 as your solution works. But I need a function to return the final html as in case of @Yoshi so I accept his answer.